# C_stri_join not found for knitr

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

I'm having trouble with knitr in Rstudio. The original Rhtml template does not compile or 'knit'. I get the error message:

```
processing file: Test.Rmd
  |.............                                                    |  20%
  ordinary text without R code

  |..........................                                       |  40%
label: unnamed-chunk-1
Quitting from lines 11-12 (Test.Rmd) 
Error in stri_c(..., sep = sep, collapse = collapse, ignore_null = TRUE) : 
object 'C_stri_join' not found
Calls: <Anonymous> ... evaluate_call -> handle_output -> <Anonymous> -> str_c -  > stri_c

Execution halted
```

I have the latest version of R, Rstudio, Rmarkdown, knitr, etc.

Comment: I don't think that this is a dup of that question. Error reported is in a different format, etc. The linked question might be useful for troubleshooting since it details methods for exploring the objects instantiated.

Comment: Let's see a `sessionInfo()` then...

Comment: Chances are you need to reinstall the **stringi** package. Without `sessionInfo()`, who knows...

Comment: I think the problem it's not related to Knitr. I get the same error message when running packages such as afex or latex2exp