# can't generate PDF with knitr R

Tags: r, pdf, powerpoint, knitr

Previously I can conveniently generate slides with knitr R from .rmd file. But this time I came across an error as listed below (it even doesn't work for the default .rmd file), does anyone know what's wrong with this, I have reinstall Rstudio, but it seems not work. My OS is MAC OS 10.9 and R version is 3.2.2 (2015-08-14).

> Error in stri_locate_all_regex(string, pattern, omit_no_match =
>   TRUE,  :    object 'C_stri_locate_all_regex' not found Calls:
>    ... parse_inline ->  -> stri_locate_all_regex
>   Execution halted

Comment: Restart your Rstudio; Update all your R packages and see how it goes?

Comment: You should try to reinstall to `stringi` package, see [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33306592/object-c-stri-join-not-found-using-knitr-in-rstudio).

Comment: Nice, I've tried, it works by reinstalling stringi!